# Specify the workbook when working on a worksheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, object, worksheet

I would like to get the value of cell. I have multiple workbooks, and some of the workbooks have sheets with the same name.

For example, `test.xlsx` and `test2.xlsx` both has a sheet named `sheet1.xlsx`

So, when working on a sheet, I would like to specify the workbook. I use `wb.sh.*expression*` all the time, and I am surprised that this does not work.

What am I missing here conceptually?

Code:

```
set wb1 = Workbooks("Test1.xlsx")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Debug.Print wb1.sh1.Range("A1").Value
```

Code which would work, but is not specific enough:

```
set wb1 = Workbooks("Test1.xlsx")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Debug.Print sh1.Range("A1").Value
```

Note: `Test1.xlsx` has a sheet named `Sheet1`

Comment: What doesn't work?  Also when setting your `sh1`s you can do `Set sh1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")`...That way you don't have to include the workbook name each time too.

Comment: This is what doesn't work: `wb1.sh1...` You can't nest declared objects like that.  It either needs to be `wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")...` or simply `sh1...`.  If you want to specify the workbook for the `sh1` variable, do it in your Set line: `Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")` and then you can check what workbook it's a part of by looking at it's .Parent.Name property: `Debug.Print sh1.Parent.Name`

Comment: How are you opening the workbooks? Looks like you're discarding the `Workbook` object reference returned by `Workbooks.Open`, somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the workbook, the `Open` method gives you the `Workbook` object reference - hold on to it instead of discarding it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

That way you never need to query the `Workbooks` collection and supply a hard-coded file name to get your workbook.

Next up, the `Worksheet` reference:

```
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

The `Worksheets` collection is a property that belongs to a `Workbook` object. Indeed, that's not "specific" enough: if you don't *qualify* the property call, then you're implicitly referring to `ActiveWorkbook` - which may or may not be the workbook you need to be using.

That's where that `wb` reference comes into play:

```
Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Lastly, what you have here:

```
Debug.Print wb1.sh1.Range("A1").Value
```

Is not only illegal, it's overkill: `sh1` *already* knows what `Workbook` object it belongs to - you can get that object reference through `sh1.Parent` and compare it to the `wb` reference:

```
Debug.Assert sh1.Parent Is wb
```

`sh1` is a local variable, not a member of the `Workbook` interface: that's why you can't do `wb1.sh1`.

> *I use wb.sh.expression all the time*

If your code ever worked, I guarantee you don't.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot.